# Finding the length of control points to obtain a specific curve length

Tags: bezier-curve, arc-length

I want to begin by letting you know that my math skills don't go far beyond basic Algebra. I can understand most concepts after a walk-through, but this one is, so far, beyond my capabilities.

What I'd like to know is a) is there a formula for finding the length of x and y control points for a bezier curve based on a specified length of the curve and, if yes, b) can someone please explain it to me in terms I can use and understand with my skill level.

Here's the long version for more context:

I use a program called Seamly to make clothing patterns. The program is open source and uses equations on a grid to produce the drafts. (Please see links for images) 
[Basic Bodice Draft using Seamly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nz7HB.jpg)

This post explains how to create a curve using the program:

https://wiki.valentinaproject.org/wiki/Creating_Smooth_Curves:_The_Kolson_Method

The problem I run into is that I want to be able to control the length of the curves so that, regardless of the size of the bodice, it will keep the proper circumference around the armhole. Thus, I need to be able to set the length of the curve. The only way to do that in the program would be to use a formula of some sort based on the measurements I know (scye depth, armhole circumference, armhole diameter, etc) to set the control points of the curve.

[the control points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DR1g6.jpg)

[The formula box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mni4k.jpg)

I was thinking based on the below video from Kahn Academy, that I could use, say, the armhole length and the length of the curve (half the circumference of the arm at the shoulder) and solve for y (the scye depth) to get a length for the control points, but I don't understand how to work back from a given length of curve.

https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-bc/bc-applications-of-integration-new/bc-8-13/v/arc-length-formula

I'm really hoping some kind soul will be able and patient enough to help me. Reading posts with endless Calculus formulas go over my head without real-world context. Thanks!